# One card in hand

Tags: canasta

A player has several melds but no canastas. The player has only one card left in his hand. He picks up a card that he can add to one of his melds - but not enough to make a canasta. Can he add that card to a meld and discard his remaining card. On the next turn he has to pick up a card and immediately discard it. Is this correct ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Frozen prize pile in canasta when all but one player has only 1 card in hand?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/21353/frozen-prize-pile-in-canasta-when-all-but-one-player-has-only-1-card-in-hand)

Comment: @GendoIkari I am not sure if that is a duplicate since it is talking about freezing the discard pile.

Answer (score 1):

They will not be able to pick up a card that they can add to an existing meld unless there are multiple cards on the discard pile.

[Rules](https://bicyclecards.com/how-to-play/canasta/)

> A player with only one card left in their hand may not take the discard pile if there is only one card in it.

Also they can't discard the last card unless they have a canasta on the table

> A player goes out when they get rid of the last card in their hand by discarding or melding it, provided that their side has melded at least one canasta or they complete a canasta while going out. Failing this requirement, a player must keep at least one card in their hand. When a player goes out, the hand ends and the results on both sides are scored.

Comment: So a player with no canastas and with just one card in his hand can simply discard the pick up for ever until someone wins. Is that correct ?

Comment: That depends, if they are just one card away from a canasta they can hope to draw the correct card. Or if they are playing with a partner they can hope their partner can finish one. Otherwise they are just out of luck and hope the other player doesn't run the score up.

Comment: So does that mean that a player has to have a card in his hand while it is not his turn or a card in his hand while it is his turn  - i.e picked up from the stock and immediately discarded

Comment: A player always has to have at least one card in hand until they go out

Comment: So that means he has to have at least two cards before he can discard ?

Comment: On your turn you will always have at least two cards, one from your hand and one that you drew from the deck.

Answer (score -4):

If they draw from the stock, they cannot add to a meld because they would go out without a canasta by discarding the other card in their hand.

> [Rules](https://bicyclecards.com/how-to-play/canasta/)
> A player goes out when they get rid of the last card in their hand by discarding or melding it, provided that their side has melded at least one canasta or they complete a canasta while going out. Failing this requirement, a player must keep at least one card in their hand.

If they draw from the discard pile, they can add it to a meld and then add the rest of the discard pile to their hand.

> [Rules](https://bicyclecards.com/how-to-play/canasta/)
> Or, if the player wishes, they may instead (subject to restrictions under "Taking the Discard Pile") take the top card of the discard pile to use it in a meld; having done so, they must take the rest of the discard pile.

At this point, they will have at least 2 cards in their hand again since the discard pile will have had at least one more card in it since they can't draw from it if there is only 1 left.  So then they can discard and still have at least 1 card in their hand.

> [Rules](https://bicyclecards.com/how-to-play/canasta/)
> A player with only one card left in their hand may not take the discard pile if there is only one card in it.

Comment: This does not appear to add any information that is not in the existing answer and it doesn't provide a source for the information.

Comment: I tried to just add a comment to your answer, but I was not allowed.  Your answer to Tony B's question in his first comment was incomplete.  You suggest they have to hope they are close enough to a canasta to draw what they need or have their partner help.  However, the rule you provided, "A player with only one card left in their hand may not take the discard pile if there is only one card in it," only applies when "there is only one card in [the discard pile]."  Since there is no rule specifying you can't pick it up if there is more than one, that means you can.

Comment: The information I added was the other option they have of drawing from the discard pile as long as there is not only one card in it.

Comment: That information is in the existing answer with the line that says they can't draw from the discard if there is only a single card in it. By the very nature of saying you can't draw from the pile if there is only a single card means you can draw from the pile if there is more than a single card in it.

Comment: Your answer doesn't include the restrictions when a player has a single card in hand.

Comment: I agree, but you said on Jul 10 '19, "Otherwise they are just out of luck and hope the other player doesn't run the score up." I almost thought this was correct until the obvious that you pointed out here dawned on me. I wanted to help anyone like me, so I added my answer. If you'd please correct your mistaken comment, I'll gladly just delete my answer.

Comment: Please read my answer again, I start out by saying "They will not be able to pick up a card that they can add to an existing meld unless there are multiple cards on the discard pile." I absolutely covered the possibility of being able  to draw from the discard pile if there was multiple cards in it. You seem to be focused on a single comment instead of looking at what was in the answer itself.

Comment: Are you saying your comment isn't wrong then? When I first read your answer, I didn't catch that they WOULD be able to pick it up if there were more than 1. I thought that meant they were "out of luck." YOU didn't seem to catch it as you put the wrong info in your comment. If the point of this is to help people, then correcting your comment would do that instead of misleading people if they read the comments and not just the answer.

Comment: The comment isn't wrong it just doesn't cover every situation and isn't required to. As I have stated multiple times my answer already states that you can draw a card from the pile if there are multiple cards in it. The comment is not part of the answer itself and my answer already covers what is in your answer.

Comment: Your comment isn't required to cover every situation, but "they are just out of luck" is wrong because it implies no other option even though they have one. Also, your answer doesn't include if they draw from the stock. That's where my confusion came from. I was merely trying to help people who were confused the same way I was, which is why I tried to add some clarification.